# Project from entity with child collection to flatened collection of dtos

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a collection of Foo objects that each have a collection of Bars.

What I want is to project my collection of Foo's to FooDTO's which will be a flattened version, one per child. How can I do that?

e.g. :

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name;
}

public class FooDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarName { get; set; }
}
```

so If I have

```
        var foos = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo
            {
                Id = 1,
                Bar = new List<Bar>
                {
                    new Bar {Name = "foobar"},
                    new Bar {Name = "barfoo"}
                }
            },
            new Foo
            {
                Id = 2,
                Bar = new List<Bar>
                {
                    new Bar {Name = "2foobar"},
                    new Bar {Name = "2barfoo"}
                }
            }
        };

var collection = Mapper.Some_kind_of_Magic(foos);
```

collection would be look like :

```
[ 
    new FooDto{ Id = 1, BarName = "foobar"}, 
    new FooDto{ Id = 1, BarName = "barfoo" } 
    new FooDto{ Id = 2, BarName = "2foobar"}, 
    new FooDto{ Id = 2, BarName = "2barfoo" } 
]
```

How can I do it? Is it possible with a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](http://stevelillis.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/useful-linq-extensions-you-might-not.html) with a *result selector* to flatten out the collection. Like so:

```
var collection = foos.SelectMany(
                                l => l.Bar, 
                                (foo, bar) => new FooDto 
                                              { 
                                                  Id = foo.Id, 
                                                  BarName = bar.BarName 
                                              });
```

You can append .ToList() if you want the collection as a list.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I ended up doing. I had hoped to do it with Automapper but I don't think it's possible.